# What python library I should use for facebook OAuth and OpenGraph

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, django-socialauth

I have designed a Facebook application and need to add OAuth, Open Graph for complete functionality. Considering that I know nothing about Open Graph and little JS, I'd like to use a small wrap-up (python lib) which will provide the those features..

I searched over Google, stackoverflow and found few projects which provide some cool features but I am unable to choose..

python libs:

1. [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth)
2. [fandjango](https://github.com/jgorset/fandjango/)
3. [facepy](https://github.com/jgorset/facepy)
4. [pyFacebook](https://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/) - I think this doesn't offer OAuth.

I also use Google Data API in my project. So, the better option would be django-social-auth but I am not sure if I can do Open Graph with it..

Can anyone tell me what is the best, maintained, good lib? 
(Please do mention if its not in the above list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`django-social-auth` is really great if you want to build a website that allows users to log in with Facebook, but if you're building an application on Facebook.com you probably want to use something like `fandjango`. Either way, you will need a different kind of library (like, say, `facepy`) to interact with Facebook's API once you've retrieved an access token from the user.

Full disclosure: I am the author of `fandjango` and `facepy`.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly suggest django-social-auth. Any library than can parse JSON will support Open Graph as FQL and Graph API data can all be retrieved from Facebook's API (REST).

Good luck!