# Facebook server-side login without PHP

Tags: php, python, facebook, web

I'm doing a project for some college work and trying to integrate facebook with their server-side login feature:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/

The only problem is its explained for PHP and I'm using python. I had a look at the overview of how it works using redirects and I intend on using the urllib2 to do HTTP requests to facebook for the whole process.

Can anyone give me a translation from PHP to Python or even pseudo-code that describes what I have to do, as I have no idea what all these PHP functions do, so I don't really know how to go about writing something equivalent to.

Thanks, Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it in Ruby, but this looks like a good start.

http://facebook-python-library.docs-library.appspot.com/facebook-python/examples/oauth.html

And something similar was asked and it seems like there are helpful links

[What python library I should use for facebook OAuth and OpenGraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355857/what-python-library-i-should-use-for-facebook-oauth-and-opengraph)

Comment: I have looked into Django-facebook but unfortunately Django seems to be a lot lot more than what I need, and a little complicated too, so I'm sticking to what I know until after the project deadline where I'm working in my own time. First link is really good though :) -- EDIT -- No rep to vote up with :(

Comment: I think facepy or pyFacebook are independent of Django.

Answer (score 0):

I have a python library that does this:

- https://github.com/jvanasco/facebook_utils

It's on PyPi as well.

The main file shows how you'd integrate it on the serverside and template for Pyramid. Doing it in Django, Flask, whatever would be similar.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not using any framework for the moment as it is a lot to get to grips with in the space of a few days. For my data requests I'm simply using Facebook FQL and for HTTP, returning strings of html (already done for me) with mod_wsgi. I simply have to do a cheap and cheerful back-end to tick the boxes, so a full on framework is a little too much. But thanks :D

Comment: The package I wrote doesn't depend on a framework ( all the ones I found when i needed to do this relied on Django or similar ).  It just has a few extra methods to simplify integration with pyramid.

Comment: Awesome, I've bookmarked it anyways, I'm just getting to grips with the first link so I know what is actually happening either way.